# my app unfortunately stopped on create layout

Tags: android

i'm making an app on android studio and my emulator stopped after opening my layout and give this message on logcat:

```
 at com.calcupital.calcupital.VancoFull.onCreate(VancoFull.java:20)
```

and head this line :

```
setContentView(R.layout.vanco_full);
```

and show me this:

```
02-28 16:07:17.799    1101-1101/com.calcupital.calcupital E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calcupital.calcupital/com.calcupital.calcupital.VancoFull}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error    inflating class <unknown>



        at com.calcupital.calcupital.VancoFull.onCreate(VancoFull.java:20)

       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

what weird me is the app works fine on my phone !!!
there is an error inside the layout and can't find it because the emulator is stopped before starting !! , 
So what is the problem here ?!!

Comment: Show more of the stacktrace.

Comment: ok i will edit m qs, also it show me this :Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: @Paul Bellora  help me

Comment: i'm using genymotion emulator !! so how i can do that !!

Answer (score 0):

It's an `OutOfMemoryError` add more memory to your emulator.

Comment: i'm using a genymotion

Comment: I'm not, so I don't know.